# How to correct "Malformed line in sources.list"

Tags: apt, updates, gtk, gedit

I know the question how to correct a malformed line in sources.list has been asked.  I tried to follow the instructions on the posted answer but I can't access sources.list when I enter `sudo -H gedit /etc/apt/sources.list` I get the following:

```
o protocol specified
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(gedit:18598): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0
bill@bill-GA-880GA-UD3H:~$
```

Comment: Try `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list` or any other terminal editor.

Comment: I'd recommend changing the title to reflect the actual issue. Maybe "Can't open sources.list in Gedit"

Answer (score 2):

Use `nano` instead:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```